# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory

Tags: java, apache, testing, jmeter

when i open apache-jmeter-3.1 and right click the test-plan button,it turns out to be no response and throws lists of errors in the jmeter.log as follows

```
2016/12/17 16:24:30 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory
at org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui.createPopupMenu(TestPlanGui.java:93)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:156)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.displayPopUp(JMeterTreeListener.java:248)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.mousePressed(JMeterTreeListener.java:193)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

what happened and how can i fix it? thanks !!! it has bothered me a long time...

Comment: verify that you are include all libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this happens when a Dependent jar is not present or in case if there is a conflicting jar with different implementation present.

Check this post
https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/jmeter-could-not-initialize-menufactory-class/

Comment: thank you very much. according to your anwser, i recognized there may have a confilcting jar. i tried to delete jars in /lib/ext one by one and finnaly found the ApacheJMeter_mail.jar effected the jmeter GUI launch.

Answer (score 126):

I've got a similar issue. **The solution was changing the theme!**

Try the following:

1. Open JMeter -> Options -> Look and Feel -> Select any other theme other than Darcula (E.g. `System` theme).
2. Restart JMeter.

source: https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/5555703.html

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to open any file. Ctrl + O was showing same error. Problem is solve by changing theme.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29863902)

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138024/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*