# Jmeter script doesn't work with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

I am running my jemeter script with jenkins but it throws below error:-

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Jmeter>H:\D\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.bat
Writing log file to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Jmeter\jmeter.log

Uncaught Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. See log file for details.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.
```

My Jenkis configuration:-

```
H:\D\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.bat
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t H:\D\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\gmail.jmx -l TestResult.jtl
```

Please help!!

Comment: same above commands are working fine from windows cmd")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196866/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-jmeter-gui)